# What happened to the "Improve Edit" and "Reject and Edit" buttons on this review?

Tags: support, review

I just reviewed [this suggested edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/491971), and while doing so, I noticed that the *Improve Edit* and *Reject and Edit* buttons were absent; only *Approve* and *Reject* were there. I haven't been suspended from editing - the *edit* link still appears under all posts, and I've never done anything bad as far as I know. The edited post wasn't a tag wiki, and I don't have permission to approve edits there anyway.

What happened there? Under what circumstances do those two buttons not appear?

Comment: Wierd. I see the buttons, and there's no suspensions/bans on your account.

Comment: FWIW, I also only see *Approve* and *Reject*.

Comment: Also, opening the question proper reveals that the answer isn't there at all.

Comment: My guess? The answer was deleted, and we don't have enough rep to see that. In the mean time, the edit had hit the review queue and was still pending when the answer was deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Michael Frank surmised, the answer is deleted. For whatever reason, that didn't automatically reject the edit; it's still hanging around, waiting to be approved or rejected.

You've earned the privilege of approving or rejecting edits, and of editing normal posts, the latter being necessary for Improve or Reject and Edit. However, you can't edit deleted posts, and if you can't edit them then you can't Improve or Reject and Edit.

I've approved the edit to remove it from the queue.